# Speed distribution of a journey

Tags: algorithm, distribution

A bike is traveling at various speeds *v*. I am looking for the fastest speed *v(d)* for any given distance *d* which is smaller than the total distance travelled. For example, over 10k total distance the bike might have a very fast 100m down some hill, but the maximum 1k speed would be lower. I want to know the maximum speed for any (sub-) distance (as a table - so not for a single *d*).

I believe the above distribution (speed over distance) is well defined but not obvious to compute efficiently. I would be interested in:

- Under what name is the problem known?
- How to compute this in the discrete case when the bike's journey is captured as a list of (distance,time) points? This limits the resolution but makes a computation possible. For simplicity, let's assume the distances in the list are evenly spaced.

Comment: Suppose that the frequency of measurements is one-per-100-metres, so that for a 10km ride you'd have 100 measurements.  Then the fastest speed over any interval is the speed between the two positions with the smallest time interval between them.  If you can find a sequence of identical speeds between measuring points you have found a distance, greater than 100m, over which the maximum speed was maintained.  I've obviously missed the point of your question because I can't see any real problem.

Comment: So you would suggest to enumerate the sub distances: 100m, 200m, 300m ... and for each scan the entire list to find the fastest speed. This has quadratic complexity and would work when the list is short enough. With data from GPS the distances would not be evenly spaced but I could interpolate evenly spaced data.

Comment: I'm not really suggesting any particular approach.  If your tuples are not evenly spaced in distance I'm not suggesting you faff about making a series from them that is evenly spaced in distance (you told us we could assume that, so I did).  I'm suggesting that if you have a sequence of `(distance, time)` tuples you have a sequence of `distance/time=speed` measurements and that's all you have.  What I struggle to understand about your question is what would be a good answer to it.  And yes, if you want to know the speed between any two points, you will have to make a `n^2` data structure.

Comment: could you explain why "For example, over 10k total distance the bike might have a very fast 100m down some hill, but the maximum 1k speed would be lower" ? to me the max 1k speed would be max(v(100), v(1k)) ?

Comment: If you assume an athletic activity, you probably can go faster over a short distance than over a long distance. So I would expect that that the maximum speed over 100m during the journey is higher than the maximum speed found over 1k. Hence, v(100m) >= v(1000m). I would expect that to hold generally: v(d1) >= v(d2) for all d1 < d2.